# Why is this not casting the correct number to playerNumber?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums, casting

This is in Unity as a Monobehaviour and it is for a single multiplayer script that would allow for multiplayer. The enum is supposed to be for the drop down selector in the inspector, the playerNumber won't update with the required numbers.

```
public enum PlayerNumber
{
    Player0,
    Player1,
    Player2,
    Player3,
    Player4,
    Bot,
}

private static int playerNumber = 0;
public PlayerNumber playerID;
public Text playerIDText;

// Use this for initialization
private void Start()
{

}

public static void PlayerControlSwitch(PlayerNumber playerNum)
{
    switch(playerNum)
    {
        case PlayerNumber.Player0:
            playerNumber = 0;
            break;
        case PlayerNumber.Player1:
            playerNumber = 1;
            break;
        case PlayerNumber.Player2:
            playerNumber = 2;
            break;
        case PlayerNumber.Player3:
            playerNumber = 3;
            break;
        case PlayerNumber.Player4:
            playerNumber = 4;
            break;
        case PlayerNumber.Bot:
            playerNumber = Random.Range(5,10);
            break;
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    playerIDText.text = "Player ID Number:" + playerNumber.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What's the point of the enum if you're just converting it to an integer? Regardless, just call `PlayerControlSwitch()` in `Start()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's your entire code, you're never calling the PlayerControlSwitch method. So before setting the text field's text, you'd need to do
`PlayerControlSwitch(playerID);`

Also if you are not changing the player number after game start, I wouldn't put these methods in the Update, otherwise Unity will do these checks every single frame.